# Conditions on a ratio of two $l_p$ norms to be a norm

Tags: vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Suppose I have a vector space upon which I have defined the $l_p$ norm. If I define a function

$$f(x) = \frac{||x||_p^{n+1}}{||x||_q^{n}}$$

then what are the conditions on on $p$, $q$ and $n$ for $f$ to be a norm? Trivially $n=1$ works, but I'm not sure how to prove for higher $n$.

Specifically, I need to prove that $f(x+y) \leq f(x) + f(y)$. Alternatively, if this is a known norm which has a name then I can go look it up.